# LinkButton value lost on PostBack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a `table` that I'm creating `rows/cells` in the code behind, and adding various controls to each cell.  There is also as `submit button` on the form.

One of the cells contains an `SPLinkButton`.  I have a `Javascript function` that changes the `innerText/textContent` based on user action from the default value set in the code behind.  Prior to clicking the Button to run code behind, the end user does see the updated text of the `SPLinkButton`.

When the submit button is clicked, this is the only control that reverts its value back to the default value during the `button's postback`.  A `Label/TextBox/DDL` all preserve their values.  If I wrap the control in `IsPostBack`, the cell the control is added to will be null (or if I wrap the entire table, there will be no rows).  **Note that I'm using the value of another item to uniquely append the SPLinkButton ID on a per-table row basis.**

```
What is different about LinkButton/SPLinkButton and postback behavior?
```

EDIT: I converted the SPLinkButton to a TextBox, providing similar functionality.  While I dislike the presentation compared to the textbox (look and feel, as well as the SPLinkButton would automatically expand the modal size when needed), it does function.  I would love to get SPLinkButton working and go back to using it, if possible.

Comment: Can you please post some actual code. thanks

Comment: I'm more looking for why the behavior is different between these controls, in other words, why a TextBox value is persisted across postbacks, where as a LinkButton value is not.

Comment: Well without code is a bit difficult but I guess the button posts and the link is not a post. The link works as a get . Without code is a bit difficult to see your problem. If you post some code you will have more people replying. cheers